# added firebase hosting record to namecheap, it's connected after added the records but static content not serving

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, namecheap

i have transfer my '.com' domain to namecheap and domain is connected successfully after insetting the TXT and A record to namecheap.
but it is not serving the hosted content from firebase instead of it is showing wordpress template. I don't know where it is come from because i have an angular template already hosted on firebase hosting.
[image: firebase hosting]
[image: namecheap details]
I am using "Namecheap basicDNS" as a Nameservers